# Convert coordinates system when parse .shp file used Python

Tags: python, coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

When I parse .shp file (used Python module pyshp), the points coordinates stored in feet coordinate system (ftUS). How I can convert this data to degrees latitude and longitude format?

```
import shapefile

sf = shapefile.Reader("test")
shapes = sf.shapes()
print(shapes[0].points)
```

result: [[1447887.395856008, 552512.2958560139]]

Comment: This can be useful
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118215/proj4-string-for-nad832011-louisiana-south-ftus But if you can find a cleaner solution I would be very interested.

Comment: Thanks, very useful! My solution was more complex and include use js implementation proj module + python.